# Excel COUNTIF formula (Skip the range order)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I need help with a formula that I am trying to drag down.

The original formula is:
 =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!N:N,"P",Sheet2!M:M,"<=3/31/17",Sheet2!M:M,">=1/1/17")

I need to drag this formula down 18 more times. However, I need the range to skip one each time. For example, if I were to drag the formula down one row it should say:
 =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!P:P,"P",Sheet2!O:O,"<=3/31/17",Sheet2!O:O,">=1/1/17")
So in that example it is skipping the "O" range at first, and then skipping the "N" range in the latter of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Index() to set the range/array:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1040000,0,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+14),"P",INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1040000,0,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+13),"<=3/31/17",INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1040000,0,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+13),">=1/1/17")
```

Now as it is dragged down the references will skip every other row.

Comment: This works for the first 8 rows. Then for whatever reason it is miscalculating the last 11 rows.

Comment: I didn't mention this before, but I need to be skipping one column each time not rows.

Comment: For this sheet I'm starting at N:N and then the next column would be P:P, then R:R, then T:T... and so on all the way to AX:AX

Comment: @JeffDoe Most likely you have data that is being skipped over.  Change `Sheet2!1:1040000` to `Sheet2!$1:$1040000`  (relative addresses will increment as you drag down the formula).